# Search for " and replace with '

Tags: regular-expression

The basic format I need it in is this.

```
%s/search/replace/c
```

So I want it to search the entire file and ask for confirmation for every match found.

Comment: `:%s/"/'/c`? I am confused what your question is, as you already mentioned the `:s` command yourself? Are you having problems with it? If so, which?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I wondered the same thing myself, and took a guess that the missing `g` flag was the issue.

Comment: That seems likely @Rich. Would still be good if the OP would clarify the question to confirm (questions are supposed to be useful for *others* too, after all).

Comment: I used the exact syntax you referenced CarpetSmoker. Maybe I had a typo  or a weird issue with Bash on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
:%s/"/'/gc
```

The `g` is important, because otherwise the command will only replace the first `"` on each line.

Comment: This worked. I thought I was typing exactly that; either I was searching the wrong file, or I need to slow down and pay attention to what I'm typing. I feel like a goofball right now, lol.

Comment: @JasparLamarCrab It happens to all of us! :)